# Weibliche Form von Kavalier für feminines 'Kavaliersdelikt'?

Tags: gender, vocabulary

Ein Karikaturist hat diese Frage im Kontext der aktuellen Medienberichte über Alice Schwarzer, Kavaliersdelikte und Steuerhinterziehung in einer Zeichnung aufgeworfen:

Wie ist die weibliche Form von Kavaliersdelikt?

Mich hat die Frage nun ernsthaft beschäftigt. Via Google gefunden habe ich:

> Vielleicht **Chevalière**, das heißt Ritterin. Kavalier kommt ja vom französischen chevalier. ([Quelle](http://de.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091024080110AAya4ij))

Daraus ergäbe sich *Chevalièresdelikt*. Klingt schön, aber *Ritterinnendelikt* trifft nicht die Bedeutung des Begriffs *Kavaliersdelikt*. Gibt es Alternativen?

Meine eigenen, zugegebenermaßen sehr kreativen Ideen:

- kleine Sünderin
- Trivial-Delinquentin<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> (abgeleitet aus dem Englischen von Kavaliersdelikt - *trivial offense*)

Comment: Mir ist nicht ganz klar wonach Du suchst. Der "Kavalier" als gesellschaftliches Phänomen hat kein weibliches Gegenstück. Das ist eher kulturell als linguistisch. Frauen hatten in dieser vergangenen Gesellschaftsform keine Rolle, die dem eines männlichen "Kavaliers" ähnlich kommt. Also gibt es da auch kein Wort für. Dann geht es in der Frage auf einmal um ein "Kavaliersdelikt". Das beinhaltet zwar das Wort "Kavalier", ist aber so stark idiomatisch, das der "Kavalier" darin nicht mehr viel mit der ursprünglichen Bedeutung zu tun hat. Bitte formuliere Deine Frage neu.

Comment: Der letzte Teil Deiner Frage klingt zudem danach, dass Du denkst, dass man durch Begehen eines Kavaliersdelikts zum Kavalier wird.

Comment: Verwandt (aber nicht identisch) und ohne jeglichen Geschlechtsbezug ist übrigens *Bagatelle* bzw. *Bagatelldelikt.*

Comment: Kavaliersdelikte sind keine Delikte die sich nur Männer herausnehmen, auch wenn die Rolle des Kavaliers eine männliche ist. Der Scriftstellerverband umfasst auch weibliche Autoren. Ansonsten wie @teylyn.

Comment: Vermutlich war [diese Karikatur](http://www.stuttmann-karikaturen.de/archivseq.php?id=5151&s=rss) Anlass für die Frage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Derivat

Es gibt kein etabliertes, konventionalisiertes Wort für einen weiblichen Kavalier, aber nach den üblichen morphologischen Mustern lässt sich ***Kavalierin*** bilden. Das funktioniert wie in *Passagierin*, *Offizierin* oder *Pionierin*. Die Endung *-ier* kann verschiedenen Ursprungs sein und hat verschiedene Aussprachen mit entsprechenden Auswirkungen; so funktioniert *Spanierin*, *Kanadierin* oder *Parlamentarierin* problemlos, wohingegen *?Premierin*, *?Bankierin* und *?Routinierin* mindestens zweifelhaft wären und daher vermieden werden.

Feminine Derivative auf *+in* bzw. eher deren Pluralformen auf *+innen* werden nur scherzhaft oder überspitzt in Feminismuskritik und manchmal frauenfeindlich als Linkselement in einem Kompositum verwendet, sonst bleibt es beim meist maskulinen Stamm ggf. mit Fugenelement, also könnte man statt *Kavalier+s+delikt* durchaus ****Kavalierinnendelikt*** verwenden und die Anspielung würde verstanden.

### Neologismus

Da das klassische Konzept des Kavaliers klar männlich ist und sich vor allem im Verhalten gegenüber Frauen (eines gewissen Standes) zeigt, könnte man es auch mit einer Neubildung versuchen, in der stattdessen dieses soziale weibliche Pendant auftaucht:

- ****Fräuleindelikt***, **Fräuleinsdelikt*
- **Maidendelikt*, **Mädchendelikt*
- **Damendelikt*, **Hofdamendelikt*
- **Weiberdelikt*, **Weibsdelikt*, **Weibchendelikt*
- **Frauendelikt* – wäre eher illegale Abtreibung o.ä., weil *Frau* eher geschlechts- als rollenbezogen verstanden wird, vielleicht aber auch der angeblich typisch weibliche Giftmord

### Synonym

Allen diesen Wörtern liegt natürlich ein anachronistischer Sexismus zugrunde, weswegen man bei ihrer Verwendung vorsichtig sein sollte. Geschlechtsunabhängig bietet sich wie schon in den Kommentaren erwähnt bspw. ***Bagatelldelikt*** an.

### Soziolinguistische Betrachtung

Ein Kavaliersdelikt ist eine Straftat oder eine Ordnungswidrigkeit, die nicht verwerflich sein und daher nicht geahndet werden soll, weil sie in der Absicht begangen wird, ein moralisch höhenwertiges Ziel zu erreichen, bspw. das ungefragte Betreten fremder Grundstücke um eine holde Maid zu freien. Es ist also ein Verbrechen, das zwar nicht legal, aber legitim ist – in den Augen dessen, der es so bezeichnet oder dem es unterstellt wird! Gerade die angeblich opferlosen Delikte, die Kavaliere wohl klassischerweise begingen, sollte man heute kritischer sehen, da das ganze Konzept die Frau zum Objekt männlichen Handelns degradiert, also zutiefst sexistisch ist, obwohl es auch für sie angenehm sein kann. Dazu gehört aber auch sowas wie das „Verführen Minderjähriger“, was manche für einen chauvinistischen Euphemismus für „Vergewaltigung“ halten.

Tatsächlich wird das Wort heute wohl hauptsächlich in Floskeln wie *… ist kein Kavaliersdelikt* verwendet. Der Bezugsrahmen dürfte häufig in Bereichen wie Steuerhinterziehung oder Straßenverkehrsvergehen und insgesamt eher bei Ordnungswidrigkeiten liegen, die keinen offensichtlichen Bezug zum geschlechtlichen Aspekt des Kavaliers mehr haben, sondern nur zum sozialen Stand, denn es sind die Bereiche, in denen (nur oder auch) besser gestellte Herren und – gefühlt seltener – Damen häufiger in Konflikt mit dem Gesetz geraten, während Raub, Mord, Vergewaltigung etc. natürlich nur von verderbten Gestalten niederen Ranges begangen werden. Das englische *white-collar crime*, das vor allem für Wirtschaftsverbrechen verwendet wird, ist ähnlich gelagert. Diese Erkenntnis eröffnet wiederum Möglichkeiten zu geschlechtsneutralen Ersatzbildungen wie *bürgerliches Delikt*, *Spießervergehen*, *Managerverbrechen*, *Mittelschichtstraftat*, *Elitenkriminalität* usw.

Answer (score 3):

Ein feminines Äquivalent zu Kavalier gibt es schlicht nicht.
Das Wort ist zwar dem Französischen entnommen, aber auch wenn es dort eine fem. Form gibt, so ist diese nicht im Deutschen als Lehnwort bekannt.

Wie teylyn im Kommentar schon sagt:
Zur Zeit, als dieses Wort entstanden ist, gab es so etwas wie Ritterinnen nicht, daher fehlt es hier in der Sprache.

Außerdem solltest du deine Frage etwas präzisieren:
Suchst du eine auf Frauen anwendbare Form von "Kavaliersdelikt" oder das fem. Gegenstück zu "Kavalier"?

Comment: Offenbar geht es hier um ein (satirisch überhöhtes) weibliches Pendant zum Kavaliersdelikt. Natürlich würde man das normalerweise nicht brauchen, aber für Schwarzer ...

Comment: Ich habe die Frage etwas präzisiert, ich such(t)e in der Tat nach nach einer femininen Variante zum Kavaliersdelikt. Ich dachte mir schon, dass es keine entsprechende Form gibt, bzw. Kavaliersdelikt genderlos ist. @Ingmar: richtig, das war natürlich satirisch, ich würde mich trotzdem über kreative Vorschläge freuen, die *Kavaliersdelikt* femininisieren(?) :)

Comment: Für Schwarzer (und niemanden sonst!) würde ich "Kavalierinnendeliktin" vorschlagen... ;-)

Comment: Oder KavalierInnendelikt ...

Comment: **Ritter-des-Spätmittelalterlichen-Frankreichs-weiblichen-Geschlechts-DeliktIn**  
Wenn schon, denn schon!

Comment: Danke für die Vorschläge! Zur Betonung des Gender Gaps schlage ich **Kavalier_Innendelikt** vor (man beachte den Unterstrich!), damit sich auch keiner aus der LSBTTIQ*-Gruppe ausgeschlossen fühlt. *\*(Lesben, Schwule, Bisexuelle, Transsexuelle, Transgender-, Intersexuelle und sog. Queermenschen)*

Comment: @CoDEmanX Wenn schon niemand ausgeschlossen werden soll, dann KavalierX_delikt. Ansonsten biete ich noch Kavaleusendelikt als Spaßform an ;)